# Android: ListView is not updating when i passed data from another activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-listview

I am new to android and i am making listview based app. In my app i have items from Acitity_2 to Activity_1. Activity_1 has the list view. when user click on ADD button of activity1 then Activity_2 will be called. Activity_2 has the EditText. The value of EditText should update the ListView. But it only takes last value of the Edittext.

Here is the code of Activity_2:

```
          Intent intent = new Intent(ItemDetails.this, MainActivity.class);
          intent.putExtra("values", values);
          startActivity(intent);
```

Code for Activity_1

```
          ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

/** Declaring an ArrayAdapter to set items to ListView */
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

protected Context context;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /** Setting a custom layout for the list activity */
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    /** Reference to the add button of the layout main.xml */
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

    /** Reference to the delete button of the layout main.xml */
    Button btnDel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDel);




    /** Defining the ArrayAdapter to set items to ListView */
   adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, list);
    list.clear();
   list.add("Aluminium foil");
   /** Setting the adapter to the ListView */
   setListAdapter(adapter);

   String val="";
   if(getIntent().getStringExtra("values")!=null &&    getIntent().getStringExtra("values").length() > 0){
       val = getIntent().getStringExtra("values");
       list.add(val);
  }                    

   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Now its overriding last value of edittext.
Suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any good ??

Set adapter first time as

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, list);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

on coming back from Activity 2

```
 String val="";
         if(getIntent().getStringExtra("values")!=null &&    getIntent().getStringExtra("values").length > 0){
    val = getIntent().getStringExtra("values");
    list.add(val);
        }                    

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

you basically dont have to create a new adapter object each time you come back

Comment: thanks but i tried this also and this is not working. I have also edit my code in the question. You can check that..Thanks a lot for all help.

Comment: you are creating a new List each time on coming back to activity A from activity B..the correct way of doing it is as suggested in a previous comment..start second Activity B with startActivityForResult and set the edittext value in the return intent..recieve the value inside onActivityResult..add that value to the list..call notifyDataSetChanged

Answer (score 0):

You should start second Activity with startActivityForResult. Then insert the value in the editext and finishing the activity sending back the result. In activity1 intercept the result in the methos onActivityResult and update the listview.

Check out this link about activity results:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Answer (score 0):

For android to update you listview, you need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()`  on your `Adapter`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough to simply update your data set, you have to let the `Adapter` know so it reads the data again and updates the list. I can't see what your adapter is called from your code, but just call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter and it should work.

Comment: thanks for reply but i want to let you know that i have used notifuDataSetChanged() as below

Comment: Thanks for reply but i want to let you know that i have used that notifyDatasetChanged method. Here is the code: /** Defining the ArrayAdapter to set items to ListView */
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, list);
       list.add("Aluminium foil");
       
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

Do this,

```
String itemVal=getIntent().getStringExtra("values");
            if(itemVal==null){

            }else{
                list.add(itemVal);

            }
adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, list);
```